# sending response to particular django websocket client from rest api or a server

Tags: python-3.x, websocket, redis, django-channels

```
consumer.py

    # accept websocket connection
    def connect(self):
    self.accept()

    # Receive message from WebSocket
    def receive(self, text_data):
     text_data_json = json.loads(text_data)
     command = text_data_json['command']
     job_id = text_data_json['job_id']
     if command == 'subscribe':
        self.subscribe(job_id)
     elif command == 'unsubscribe':
        self.unsubscribe(job_id)
     else:
        self.send({
            'error': 'unknown command'
        })

   # Subscribe the client to a particular 'job_id'
   def subscribe(self, job_id):
    self.channel_layer.group_add(
        'job_{0}'.format(job_id),
        self.channel_name
    )       

   # call this method from rest api to get the status of a job
   def send_job_notification(self, message, job_id):
    channel_layer = get_channel_layer()
    group_name = 'job_{0}'.format(job_id)
    channel_layer.group_send(
    group_name,
    {
        "type": "send.notification", 
        "message": message, 
    }
)   

# Receive message from room group
def send_notification(self, event):
    message = event['message']
    # Send message to WebSocket
    self.send(text_data=json.dumps(
     message))
```

In the above code what I am trying to do is connect clients to the socket and subscribe clients to a particular "job_id" by creating a group called "job_1" using "subscribe" method and add it to the channel layer. Creation of groups are dynamic.

I am using below "simple websocket client extension" from Google to connect to the above websocket. I am able to make a connection with the websocket and send request to it as shown in the picture below.

[image]

Now since the client is connected and subscribed to a particular "job_id",
I am using "Postman" to send notification to the above connected client(simple websocket client extension) subscribed to particular "job_id" by passing in the job_id in the request as highlighted in yellow below.

when I do a post to the "REST-API" I am calling "send_job_notification(self, message, job_id)" method of "consumer.py" file along with the "job_id" as '1' shown in the picture below in yellow

[image]

After doing all this I don't see any message sent to the connected client subscribed to a "job_id" from the "REST-API" call.

Any help would be highly appreciated as it has been dragging on for a long time.

Edit:

thank you for the suggestion Ken its worth to make the method as "@staticmethod" but Ken how do I make the API send job status updates to the connected Clients because my long running jobs would run in some process and send update messages back to the backend via REST-API and the updates then need to be sent to the correct Client (via websockets).

My API call to the socket consumer is as below:

`from websocket_consumer import consumers 
  class websocket_connect(APIView): 
   def post(self, request, id): 
    consumers.ChatConsumer.send_job_notification("hello",id)`

My socket consumer code is as below:
[image]

**Edit**

```
`CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
"default": {
    "BACKEND": "channels_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer",
    "CONFIG": {
        "hosts": [("localhost", 6379)],
    },
},
```

}`
As you can see 'Redis' service is also running
[image]

**Edit-1**

[image]

Comment: Can you post the code in the REST API that calls the consumer method?

Comment: posting screenshots here is strongly discouraged as it is difficult for people to copy your code and try it out. Please post the formatted code instead

Comment: Again, I'm finding it difficult to understand your question. You want to send job status updates? how do you get the updates? You can send them from the process doing the job by calling the send_job_notification and passing the job status/progress as the message. But again, I probably didn't understand you correctly

Comment: I tried to format the code Ken but the editor was throwing error, so I have added screenshot. Yes you are right I get the updates from the process doing the job and those updates are given to the API and then the API calls the 'send_job_notification' passing in the 'message' and 'job_id' as parameters to send job notifications to the connect 'websocket' clients. Hope you understood.

Comment: Great. So what is your question then if you already figured that out? is the issue the errors in the screenshot? as you can see you have extra ` that needs to be removed and the json package also needs to be imported

Comment: No the issue is not in the screenshot. I am able to call the 'send_notification' method from my API using "Postman" but the notification is not sent to the clients connected to Websocket listening to group named "job_id" for status updates, which is sent thru the API. if you see my original post the clients are google chrome's "simple websocket client extension".

Comment: Does `send_notification` get called? can you put a print statement there to be sure? Which channel layer are you using? redis?

Comment: yes it is getting called Ken but the method 'send_notification' is not getting called from 'send_job_notification' static method. Yes I am using 'redis'.

Comment: Not sure I understood you. `send_notification` is not getting called when you call `send_job_notification`? Are you sure about that? if so then the issue maybe that your channel layer is not configured correctly or the client is not connected, or the group name is wrong

Comment: if you can share your email I can probably send you the code in debug mode for you to take a look is that fine for you ?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't, but if you can add as much info here as possible, I or some other person should be able to help. Add the settings of your channel layer and other parts of your code that may be useful to find the issue

Comment: Ken I have included 'channel_layer' settings and 'Redis' service info in my original post please take a look. I believe everything is set correctly. Ken one question does the API should also be connected to socket ? Since Clients are connected to the socket does that mean API should also be connected to socket to send the notifications? If you see my API code I am directly calling 'send_job_notification' static method without connecting to socket.

Comment: If it is from the same code base then it does not need to connect by websocket. Can  you post the API code where you make the call? Are you sure that the client successfully subscribed and was added to the group? you can use print statements to check this

Comment: Ken you can find the API code in my original post under "Edit:". when I tried to print if client is added to group or not I get   "<coroutine object RedisChannelLayer.group_add at 0x0000016D137049E8>"  that means I believe it is added to the group.

Comment: Can you edit your post to include the print statements? That will help. Also add a print statement in the API code and send_job_notification method

Comment: Hi Ken, I have updated the post with print statements you can find the same under **Edit-1** in my original post. The question is how "send_job_notification" static method sends status of a job to its connected clients? It should call "send_notification" method to notify its connected clients, which it is not doing.

Comment: Hi Ken, did you get a chance to look at the changes I had posted ?

Comment: I didn't look at it afterwards. From the screenshots I can see that you are subscribing to `job` but trying to send status to `job_1`. That is most likely the reason(or atleast one of the reasons) it is not working

Comment: that's a good catch, however I am trying to send notification to the subscribed clients from an API call. For API call I am using `Postman` and `Postman` is not able to send the notifications to the subscribed clients. I am using google Chrome's extensions for `WebSocket` as clients.

Comment: Have you tried fixing the bug I pointed out? it will definitely not work if not fixed. The group you subscribe to has to be the same group you're sending notifications to. In one part you have `"job{0}".format(job_id)` while in the other you have `"job_{0}".format(job_id)`. Fix this and check again

Comment: I fixed it and tested Ken, as I mentioned above it is not sending the notification to the clients from an REST API

Comment: Well I don't know then. Doesn't really where you invoke the consumer from as far as you do it correctly using the channel layer. So it shouldn't matter that it is in the view or any other part of the code

Comment: well I get this error when I call the subscribed client from a REST API using Postman. Any suggestions `AssertionError: Expected a `Response`, `HttpResponse` or `HttpStreamingResponse` to be returned from the view, but received a `<class 'NoneType'>`
HTTP POST /api/Simulation/web_socket/1 500 [1.08, 127.0.0.1:61815]`

Comment: It seems you don't return a reponse in the view after calling the consumer method. The view method has to return a response

Answer (score 1):

You cannot call the method in the consumer directly from an external code because you need to get the particular consumer instance connected to your client. This is the job of the channel layer achieved by using a message passing system or broker as reddis. 
From what I can see, you're already going towards the right direction, except that the `send_job_notification` is an instance method which will require instantiating the consumer. Make it a static method instead, so you can call it directly without a consumer instance

```
@staticmethod
def send_job_notification(message, job_id):
    channel_layer = get_channel_layer()
    group_name = 'job_{0}'.format(job_id)
    channel_layer.group_send(
    group_name,
    {
        "type": "send.notification", 
        "message": message, 
    }
```

And in your API view, you can simply call it as:
`ChatConsumer.send_job_notification(message, job_id)`

Comment: Please add the code to the original post and format it well so that it is readable.
Also, don't post screenshots of errors. Post the traceback instead as it is not readable that way

Comment: Ken as suggested I have edited the original post can you please take a look. I have marked the changes under "Edit:"